# Code blocks leak in user profile

Tags: bug

I found a weird behavior in user profile. The code blocks span beyond the boundary as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Ah.... I just realized that the new theme is the source of problem.

Comment: seems related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316111/stack-exchange-usercard-squeezer-on-profile-page , but there they claimed this was fixed ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this issue has been fixed.

[image]